# Smee-client is not working for Jenkins freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, webhooks, smee

I am trying to use Smee client to trigger the Job in Jenkins from git webhook. I created the new freestyle job in Jenkins and commit any change in the git, I am able to trigger the Job in Jenkins. When I tried to made any change in the git 2nd time, smee getting the response from git but job not triggered in the Jenkins. If I remove the 1st build in the Jenkins and commit the changes in git it's working.

```
smee --url https://smee.io/XXXXXxxxxxxx --target http://127.0.0.1:8080/github-webhook/
```

Any one please help me on this issue and how to configure smee client for Jenkins freestyle Job.